# Can Wiki js Connected to Bitbucket

Tags: java, bitbucket, wiki.js

Is it possible to do the connect the Product Documentation Done in wiki js to Bitbucket Repository to perform the pull request when required. Like i have 3 repositories Master-->Developemnt-->Product1,Product2,Product3, now if i want to merge Product 1 and Product 3 repo to Development and development to Master. Can this be done in Wikijs using BitBucket.